# wordpress not getting post id

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

the post id is not coming properly

In my jQuery 
For example if post id is 1234 it will show as `postid:1290`.
This is my code calling my action at jQuery.

```
$("#vote").not(".disabled").click(function() {
    var el = $(this);
    el.html('<span id="loader"></span>');
    var nonce = $("input#voting_nonce").val();
    var data = {
        action: 'add_votes_options',
        nonce: nonce,
        postid: '<?php echo $post->ID; ?>,',
        ip: '<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>'            
    };
```

Comment: What WP template is being used for this? Depending on where you are in The Loop, it's possible that $post is not what you think it is. Also, if you are in a function, you may need to add `global $post;`.

Comment: I am using twenty eleven theme  and the code as U mentioned above is at footer.php @david

Comment: Ok, then $post will simply be the last Post that WP actioned. For example, if you have a list of Posts in your sidebar, then $post (which is a global variable) will always be the last of those, hence why you are not getting what you expected. Is the ID you are after from a Post displayed on a single page (single.php)? If so, I'd add a hidden input and then call that using jQuery - let me know if that's the case and I'll do some example code.

Comment: I am also running a query in single.php to get related post .Is that effecting it

Comment: Yes it is displayed at single.php @david

Answer (score 1):

what does `var_dump($post)` gives you? And what does `var_dump($post->ID)` return?

**PS** I see a typo: `'<?php echo $post->ID; ?>,',` will give a double comma remove the commma within the quotes: `'<?php echo $post->ID; ?>',`

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error:  `'<?php echo $post->ID; ?>,',` - remove the first coma

Answer (score 0):

Let open network tab in developer tool (F12) to see your ajax post request and check postid parameter value.